# sumar variables de un arreglo Java

Tags: java, bluej

Tengo un arreglo con 12 elementos, cada uno es un mes del año y tienen asignado una cantidad de dias respectivamente

```
int Enero=31;
int Febrero=28;

int diciembre=31;

int cantidades[]=   {Enero,Febrero,Marzo,Abril,Mayo,Junio,Julio,Agosto,Septiembre,Octubre,Noviembre};
```

Tambien tengo un par de atributos llamados *Dia* y *Mes* con los cuales debo realizar una cuenta regresiva para saber cuantos dias faltan para el primero de enero del año siguiente , es decir introducir dos numeros por ejemplo 1(Mes) 2(Dia).
Hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente pero no funciona debido a que el indice se sale del limite pero no se como solucionarlo de una manera que funcione (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:-1 at Fechas.cuentaRegresiva)

Necesito contar los dias de cada mes junto con los dias del mes actual

```
public int cuentaRegresiva(){
 int diasTotales;
 int diasTranscurridos=0;
 int diasFaltantes;
 int iterador=Mes;
 int contador=2;

while (contador<13){
 diasTranscurridos+=cantidades[iterador-contador];
 contador+=1 }
 diasTranscurridos=diasTranscurridos+Dia;`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, no sé si será un error al copiarlo aquí, pero en el array de cantidades faltaría Diciembre:

```
int cantidades[]={Enero,Febrero,Marzo,Abril,Mayo,Junio,Julio,Agosto,Septiembre,Octubre,Noviembre, Diciembre};
```

En cuanto al error, es referido a que estás tratando de acceder a posiciones inexistentes en el array (las cuales irían de 0 a 11 en este caso), es decir, en el bucle while estás tratando de acceder a posiciones negativas ya que, por ejemplo, si quisieras probar a sacar los días de Marzo, la variable contador continuaría yendo hasta 12, tratando de acceder a posiciones como cantidades[-5]. Algo más correcto sería iniciar iterador igual a Mes-1 (por ejemplo, Marzo representa la posición 2) e ir sumando los días de los meses que son mayores o iguales a 0 que es Enero (accediendo únicamente con la variable iterador y eliminando la variable contador), es decir:

```
public int cuentaRegresiva(){
        int diasTotales;
        int diasTranscurridos=0;
        int diasFaltantes;
        int iterador=Mes-1;
        while (iterador>0){
             diasTranscurridos+=cantidades[iterador];
             iterador-=1; }
        diasTranscurridos=diasTranscurridos+Dia;
    }
```

Comment: Si fue un error lo de diciembre, me falto escribirlo aqui.

Comment: bien lo probe con el primero de enero y funciono pero con el primero de diciembre me retorna 48 xq?

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que sumar los meses completos que te faltan hasta el año siguiente y luego los días del mes en el que estás, además, como ha dicho @Galante96 te falta Diciembre en tu array.

Para sumar los días de los meses completos tienes que hacer:

```
for(int i=11; i>=mes; i--){
    diasTotales = diasTotales + meses[i];
}
```

Ahora solo tienes que sumar los días que te faltan del mes en el que te encuentras:

```
diasTotales = diasTotales + meses[mes] - dias;
```

Entre todo te quedaría:

```
public int cuentaRegresiva(int dia, int mes){
    int diasTotales = 0;

    for(int i=11; i>=mes; i++){
        diasTotales = diasTotales + cantidades[i];  //Sumamos los días de los meses completos hasta fin de año
    }

    diasTotales = diasTotales + cantidades[mes-1] - dia;  //Sumamos los días del mes introducidpo que nos faltan hasta fin de mes

    return diasTotales;
}
```

Comment: Ese codigo resulta en "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12"

Comment: en la linea de diasTotales= diasTotales+cantidades[i];

Comment: Acostumbrado a hacer los bucles incrementales... tiene que ser i-- en la declaración del for, no i++, ahí me equivoqué. Lo edito y lo dejo arreglado, gracias

Comment: Gracias a ti! es mi primer curso de java y soy muy nuevo. pero aun asi con i-- me sale el mismo error pero -1 en vez de 12

Comment: en el caso de que el mes de la cuenta regresiva sea Enero osea 1

Comment: Si, pensaba que le meterías la fecha de otra manera (que contarías los meses empezando por 1). Para hacerlo así, tienes que hacer for(int i=11; i>mes; i++) y cambiar también donde pone cantidades[mes-1] por cantidades[mes]. De todas maneras, teniendo la base ya, deberías de ser capaz de ver porqué falla, es un error sencillo de ver

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una variable de suma que almacene primero los días que lleva el mes en concreto:

```
diasTotales = cantidades[mes - 1] - dia;
```

Y luego sumar a esa variable todos los días faltantes en tu arreglo:

```
for (int i = mes; i < cantidades.length; i++) {
    diasTotales += cantidades[i];
}
```

He hecho una pequeña clase que lo ejemplifica:

```
public class SumArray
{
    private int[] cantidades = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void contarDias()
    {
        int dia;
        int mes;
        do
        {
            dia = input.nextInt();
            mes = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(cuentaRegresiva(dia, mes));
        } while (dia > 0 && mes > 0);
    }

    private int cuentaRegresiva(int dia, int mes)
    {
        int diasTotales = cantidades[mes - 1] - dia;
        for (int i = mes; i < cantidades.length; i++)
        {
            diasTotales += cantidades[i];
        }
        return diasTotales;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SumArray().contarDias();
    }
}
```